# Raid10 Shows 5 Active Drives!

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, raid10

I built two raid 10 arrays during an Ubuntu 22.04 Server install, and the system works fine, but one of the two RAID 10 arrays shows all five drives (1 that should be a spare) in "Working" status! **Naturally, I'd like it to have four working drives and one active standing by, so any input on how to get there would be appreciated!**.

Each member drive has four partitions: Grub, Raid Array 1 member partition, Raid Array 2 member partition, and Unused/Other/Swap Space.

The array in question is the one containing the "/" mount point and the "/boot" mount point.  The other array has "/Home" and a couple custom mount points for mysql databases and file shares.  Again, the system boots and everything works!  But I'm not sure what to do about the impossibility of odd numbered drives in "working" status on a RAID10 right before my eyes! I've built up dozens of systems like this and this is a first!

Here's the mdadm detail output:
/dev/md126:
Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Mon Feb 26 06:49:23 2024
Raid Level : raid10
Array Size : 838530560 (799.69 GiB 858.66 GB)
Used Dev Size : 335412224 (319.87 GiB 343.46 GB)
Raid Devices : 5
Total Devices : 5
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

```
 Intent Bitmap : Internal

   Update Time : Thu Feb 29 00:55:30 2024
         State : clean 
Active Devices : 5
```

Working Devices : 5
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

```
        Layout : near=2
    Chunk Size : 512K
```

Consistency Policy : bitmap

```
          Name : ubuntu-server:126
          UUID : 
        Events : 4840

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       19        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   1       8       35        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2       8       51        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
   3       8       67        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
   4       8       83        4      active sync   /dev/sde3
```

Any thoughts?